# Running a T-SQL script under different credentials using SQLCMD.exe utility

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I created a batch file and placed the following line into it:

```
runas /user:internal\c39293 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -E -S WLDZ9454 -d ChadDb -Q "usp_Test"
```

I was trying to run the stored procedure usp_Test on the server WLDZ9454 against the ChadDb database.

When I execute it, I just get info regarding param options, no error mesage, so it isn't clear to me what I am doing wrong.

Note that when I run the code minus the code that attempts to run under different credentials, it works:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -E -S WLDZ9454 -d ChadDb -Q "usp_Test"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's because you have not enclosed the program you are running and its parameters in quotes.

SqlCmd is therefore executed without any parameters.

```
 runas /user:internal\c39293 """C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE"" -E -S WLDZ9454 -d ChadDb -Q ""usp_Test"""
```

Comment: Close. This did it: runas /user:internal\c39293 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE -E -S WLDZ9454 -d ChadDb -Q "usp_Test"". thanks.